# Using Slider jquery with CreateElement

Tags: jquery, slide

I made images array with jquery like this.

```
        var images = [ '/image/01.jpg', '/images/02.jpg', 'images/03.jpg' ];

        function buildImages() {
            // the container
            var container = document.getElementById('mimages');
            var imgList = document.createElement('ul');
            imgList.className = 'mobile-slider';

            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

                // create the image element
                var imgListItem = document.createElement('li');
                var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
                imageElement.setAttribute('src', images[i]);
                // append the element to the container

                document.getElementById("mimages").appendChild(imgList).appendChild(imgListItem).appendChild(imageElement);
            }
        }

        // run the script here.
        buildImages();
```

Then I want to make slide with Bxslider. So I put this code.

```
             $('.mobile-slider').bxSlider({
                mode: 'horizontal',
                speed: 800,
                auto: true
            });
```

But, unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it. please help me. :(

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_, what doesn't work exactly? The `bxSlider` control is not being initialized? It is being initialized but doesn't work as expected? You need to be more specific. Update your question to include a more specific description of the problem/any console errors you are getting. It would be useful to see the HTML code aswell.

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide a [MCVE]